# offline undeploy war from glassfish

Tags: glassfish

I've got Glassfish 2.1.1 here and I need to undeploy war application. Problem is that the application is corrupted and prevents the Glassfish server from starting, so I need to undeploy it while server is down.

`asadmin undeploy` need conenction to running server...

So the question is - how to undeploy from off-line Glassfish server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. delete directory `domains/$YOUR_DOMAIN/applications/j2ee-*/$YOUR_APPLICATION` (thanks, [chris_l](https://serverfault.com/users/37454/chris-l))
2. clean out `domains/$YOUR_DOMAIN/generated/*/j2ee-*/$YOUR_APPLICATION`
3. remove all entries regarding `$YOUR_APPLICATION` from `domains/$YOUR_DOMAIN/config/domain.xml` (usually there are two records - one in `domain>applications>web-module` and one in `domain>servers>server>application-ref`)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply deleting the application's directory `domains/$YOUR_DOMAIN/applications/$YOUR_APPLICATION`? Make a backup first!

Comment: Yes I did. Does not work.
Glassfish have got some data about deployed apps in domains.xml.